# How to disable ipv6 adrress resolve in DNS

Tags: linux, dns, ipv6, nslookup

I want to disable ipv6 resolve.

When I do nslookup for host name it is giving 2 ip addresses i want to disable ipv6 address permanently. I'm using im6q sabrelite board yocto build.
Linux version is 3.14

```
nslookup c1457415477.mgr.gcsp.cddbp.net 
Server:    172.16.1.90
Address 1: 172.16.1.90 hobbes.local

Name: c1457415477.mgr.gcsp.cddbp.net
Address 1: 209.10.41.84 service.gracenote.com
Address 2: 64:ff9b::602e:9622
```

Thank you for your time.

Answer (score 1):

The IPv6 answer you see is from a DNS64 resolver. That would indicate that IPv6 is important on that network (and that the network might go IPv6-only) and you're better off not disabling it.

That aside, if you really want to filter out IPv6 results I think the only option you have is to run your own DNS resolver where you filter out all AAAA records. This is not easy and will likely break things. See https://serverfault.com/questions/554085/can-i-configure-a-dns-cache-not-to-forward-aaaa-queries for more information.